# All fields of model are required but i need some fields for update Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to update some fields but model all fields of model are required. so when it checks **ModelState** in post method that return false because all fields are required.So how i can update two fields using this model or any other way.

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="The Name field is required")]       
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required]       
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post))
{                       
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Your Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">User Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "User Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  }
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Name(int id)
    {
       var SingleUserDetails = DB.Users.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
       return View(SingleUserDetails);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Name(User userobject)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, but you might be able to just use `public ActionResult Name([Bind("FullName,UserName")]User userobject)`. I'm not sure how you are going to find the user without the ID though

Comment: ID not written here but i am using in actual code so the way you tell that is Right ?

Comment: create a view model that contains only the information you need to satisfy your view.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using model in the `Post` method of the controller. You should create a `ViewModel` with just the fields that are coming from the view.

```
public class UserVM
{
public int Id {get; set; }
public string FullName { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

After that you need to find the user that you want to update and apply the new settings

Comment: +1 this is a good answer for many reasons. 1 of these reasons being security related in that this approach prevents against overposting and underposting attacks. note any properties here that are needed should be marked as such with the `[Required]` annotation